# Is it possible to theme node add form in drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I am using zen drupal-7 sub theme. I have created a content type named *edison*. I need to change the node add form for the user. I've tried adding **page--node--add--edison.tpl.php** in **template.php**. I used the following code:

```
if (isset($variables['node'])) {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . str_replace('_', '--', $variables['node']->type);
}
```

When the `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']` variable is printed, it looks like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => page__node 
  [1] => page__node__add 
  [2] => page__node__add__edison 
  [3] => page__node__edison 
)
```

The custom .tpl is not overriding the page.tpl.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]` only suggests theme for the node itself not the form to add content!

**You have to let us know how exactly do you want to display your form. Some times a few CSS codes may be enough.**

Anyway to theme the node add content you can use `hook_form_alter` to add some attributes to the form elements, add CSS classes or ... . You can also use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to get the fields ID or class names then use CSS to theme them.

The following code

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { 
      print $form_id;
}
```

gives you the ID of the form. Find the ID of the node add form and do the changes. like

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { 
      if($form_id == "NODE_ADD_FORM")
            ////
}
```